# Hidden IFrame disables scrolling on Android browser

Tags: android, html

When a document contains a hidden IFrame, the default Android Gingerbread browser seems to disable scrolling of the document. Tested on Samsung Galaxy S.

test here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/2jSAb/show/

the fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/2jSAb/

This happens only on hidden IFrames.
Proof: when the IFrame is visible the bug doesn't occur: http://fiddle.jshell.net/beczR/show/

On ICS devices it seems resolved. 
Is there a known fix? I didn't find anything on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced this same issue yesterday with the project I am working on and just found a fix today right now.

The solution I came up with was to make the containing div of the iframe have a height of 0 instead of display: none. I have the div that contains the iframe have the following style:

```
.video {
height: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
}
```

this way it acts as a kind of display:none, but will not cause the same problem as the display none provides.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a device- or manufacturer-specific bug - it works fine on my motorola atrix running gingerbread. I'd suggest contacting samsung if it is really important that you find a fix.

Comment: +1 for testing. Will be accepted as answer if nobody else has a concrete solution.

Comment: just tested on a froyo (2.2) emulator, the bug repro'd. My atrix is 2.3.6 gingerbread; if you are running 2.3.3 perhaps it was fixed in an update?

Comment: it's a gingerbread.xxkps, which is a 2.3.6 samsung specific release.

Comment: Same bug on Samsung Ace (GT-S5830) with 2.3.7 cyanogenmod 7.2.0-cooper